# Understand price impact and liquidity in uniswap

Tags: ethereum, solidity, decentralized-applications

I am trying to understand how the price impact and liquidity was calculated in uniswap through the router contract?

Router Contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d

Is there is any direct method or what calculations need to do in my code? Pl. Guide me.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at the contract source code at https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d#code

eg. in the "addLiquidity" functions.

Also that might help :
https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/advanced-topics/understanding-returns/

Comment: Thanks. How we can calculate price impact before swap?

Comment: I think you can use an Oracle (ChainLink).

Answer (score 1):

I have answered the question here: [How to calculate Deposit Amounts for Adding Liquidity within Uniswap V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68517117/how-to-calculate-deposit-amounts-for-adding-liquidity-within-uniswap-v3)

The excel formulas can be found with the sheet: [Excel File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EXqXeXysknbib3_WbUB-lGGknBjxJvt4/view?usp=sharing)